# Clone element off-screen with identical appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a utility to accurately clamp multi-line text to a given maximum number of lines. The approach I'm taking is to binary search the text of the element to find the maximum number of words where if the element contains only those words and an ellipsis, its height is not greater than what I determine is the height for N lines.

Since this is basically a trial-and-error method, I'll need to change an element that's actually rendered and check its size. I'd like it to be some other element than the actual one the user sees, because it'd be weird to have its contents blink around for a bit as the page loads. But since the clamp location will very much depend on the precise styling of the original element, I think what I'll need is to make an exact duplicate of it that's not visible to the user but still has the browser lay it out.

How do I accomplish this using JavaScript or jQuery?

I've considered creating an element at say x=-1000000, y=-1000000, and set its style properties to the uhh... computed style of the original element? I don't think that would actually work because the computed style already considers the current content of the element. What I need is some way to get all the style *declarations* that apply to the given element; or maybe make the new element an absolutely positioned sibling of the original, but since that's outside the regular block flow, I'm not sure its sizing would work the same.

Or is there some general way to make 'invisible' temporary changes to the style of an element that still let me access what the rendering engine makes of them?

Comment: Could you please explain the use case for this? Maybe there's a better way to solve the problem. Two things that come in mind are like the obscure DOM objects like DOMparser and such. Maybe they have methods to help. Using z-index to place the clone directly under its source could work. Position:relative instead of absolute might 'fix' the issue you mention. In the end I would just give up and put the font size as a relative unit of the container size, so the font gets smaller instead of taking up more lines if they overflow the container size.

Comment: @Shilly - users can give posts titles of arbitrary length. We display posts with thumbnails in a grid. We need to constrain the size of any given post’s title to something reasonable to have an aligned grid that doesn’t look janky. I’ve floated a simpler solution to the bosses but I want to hedge against them wanting the complex one by planning an approach that won’t break if e.g. somebody changes the font two years down the line.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically add a `grid-row-span` to posts that are longer than the max amount of lines? Else I don't understand how this complex algo will fix the issue. What arguments did they have against using a basic css ellipsis on posts that overflow the grid?

Comment: @Shilly no, this has nothing to do with the grid layout. I’m talking about a `div`, with a fixed width, and arbitrarily long text in it, where I want to change said text at load time so there’s no more than two lines of text in it.

Comment: @Shilly the problem with text-overflow is that it only supports the limit being exactly one line of text, which isn’t enough to remain descriptive

Comment: What about just placing a span with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` as the last line ? Or what this guy suggest: http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Comment: I would go for single line ellipsis and a tooltip with the entire title in it on hover, since the complexity involved with calculating styles and such is just not worth it.

Comment: @Shilly Two spans with text overflow just doesn’t make any sense, I only need the continuation on the last line, and then I still need to figure out what text goes into the first span and what goes into the rest. Figuring out how much text fits on one line dynamically is literally the same problem as doing so for two or three lines. As for the pure CSS solution, I’ve seen it, it requires fixing the line-height, and requires justifying the text to not appear completely dumb, and the ellipsis in the margin just looks awkward, and will look more so in a grid of similar elements

Comment: @Shilly i hope my highers up agree with you there, since I do, but experience has taught me they’re not always reasonable when it comes to these calls

Comment: Hmm, since it's a grid, there's also a fixed height. Let the text overflow hidden? and put the grid height as 2 * fontsize + paddign and such so only two lines fit?

Comment: @Shilly a fade out at a fixed block height is another alternative I floated to them, but it’s against the task as written. As I mentioned, I’m trying to get ahead of things so I proposed all the simple alternative solutions to the person making the call, I just don’t want to be caught unprepared if they say no to them.

Comment: I remember crocking around with an ellipsis inside a <textarea> made to look like a header element. Would that be useful? It's been a couple of years though, so don't have it like right away.

Comment: Ok, so when you use a monospaced font type, the width of each character is a fixed ratio compared to the font size. So what I did was put an event handler on the element that would cut the text once text.length exceeds the `element_width / width_per_character * max_amount_of_rows`. But yeah, one of your requirements is probably to use a specific font.